# Running different Forms at Once

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to display 2 different Forms at the same time.  I tried the following code, but it's not working:

```
Form1 t1 = new Form1();
Form2 t2 = new Form2();
t2.Show();
t1.Show();

Application.Run();
```

I also tried to run the first one from program.cs and the other one from `Form1_Load`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
}
```

This doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I run multiple forms at the same time?

Comment: there is nothing wrong at your code, both has to work correct

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what were you expecting and what actually happened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a new `ApplicationContext` to represent multiple forms:

```
public class MultiFormContext : ApplicationContext
{
    private int openForms;
    public MultiFormContext(params Form[] forms)
    {
        openForms = forms.Length;

        foreach (var form in forms)
        {
            form.FormClosed += (s, args) =>
            {
                //When we have closed the last of the "starting" forms, 
                //end the program.
                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref openForms) == 0)
                    ExitThread();
            };

            form.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Using that you can now write:

```
Application.Run(new MultiFormContext(new Form1(), new Form2()));
```

Comment: +1 And today I learned how to use ApplicationContext! SO never ceases to surprise me...

Comment: @Abhinav, I've used it many times myself. It's great for allowing you to run an application with a notify icon without trying to hide the form hosting the icon! With this, you can decouple the icon and the form(s)!

Comment: Not sure there is a need for the `Interlocked`...it all runs on the main UI thread.

Comment: @tcarvin Meh, it doesn't really cost anything though.  Locking on an uncontested lock is the optimized case, and with only a handful of forms it's not going to ever, possibly, in anyone's wildest dreams, be a performance hotspot.  Would it be a bug to remove it, probably not, but is it worth my time to sit there and ask myself if it might be a bug, no.  Just throwing the lock up is the easy way of not needing to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new windows forms application for C# in Visual Studio it will get you working with a single form, and then you can add more forms in your main form. As a bonus, you will get a designer for your main form where you can drag and drop controls.

Answer (score -1):

Hope your `Program.cs` looks like:

```
 static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());

    }
```

and try this inside `Form1`:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Form2 form2 = new Form2();
      form2.Show();
  }
```

Comment: Note that if you do this closing the first form will end the application, but closing the second form won't.

Comment: everything looks exactly the same. but in spite of that it's still not working, that's why i ask here.

Comment: Make sure Form1's Load event has Form1_Load as a subscriber.