# Form is running on processes even after close the program

Tags: c#, process, terminate

I was created a C# program using 2 forms. I add both of them a exit button with **close();** method.But when i run the executable file , even if i close the program with exit button still the program run on processes at task manger. I believe its something related with one form closing but the other one was loaded to the memory and not stopping. Such situations. how come we terminate the complete program without it not storing at memory? **close();** method not enough?

Comment: What's the code for the `[STAThread]` look like?

Comment: How come i find the [STAThread] ?

Comment: There is generally a file named `Program.cs` in the project. That's the file that actually *runs* the application. There will be a method marked with `[STAThread]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running different Forms at Once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108744/running-different-forms-at-once)

Comment: thanks for yours reply my friends. i think @Reed gives me a possible solution . i will look forward to work on his method since i am beginner. if any problem occurs i will let  you all know :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways this could occur.  Some of the more common include:

1. If you use [`Application.Run()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (instead of `Application.Run(someForm)`) to start the application, it will run until you call `Application.Exit` or use another method to shut it down.  Closing the forms will not shut down the application
2. If you start a thread, via `new Thread`, and don't make it a background thread, that will also keep the program alive.  Processes will stay alive until all foreground threads have completed.  You can work around this by making the thread a background thread (or using the `Task` class instead of a `Thread`).